# Will Github Pages servers allow .htaccess and .htpasswd?

Tags: html, .htaccess, github, github-pages, .htpasswd

I am just wondering if I can use the script found here (https://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess) with Github Pages. Are the servers right for this sort of script? I know it definitely works with Apache servers but I don't know what type of servers Github have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Github pages let you host static content. That is all.

No server side code. No reconfiguring of their servers. No authentication. Just static content.

Comment: A hosting service could allow you to "host static content" and "reconfigure the server with .htaccess". Github pages **just** let you host static content.

Comment: I've never heard of that hosting service before.

Comment: Quentin, I use [**.htaccess**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/.htaccess) in my GitHub Pages site, and it's worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess, but .htpassword doesn't work. Also,

```
<Files>
```

doesn't work.